# How do I add serialized field for a function in Unity?

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine

I need to put a function from one class into another. And I want to put in the serialized field not the whole GameObject of the desired class, but one function from this class. How should I do it?
For example, I have a class GameActions describing game events.

```
public class GameActions : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void actionStart()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Game");
    }
}
```

And I want to be able to fire a function actionStart in another class by putting it into serialized field (inside of toggleEnd, for example).

```
public class Countdown : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private SomeType toggleEnd;

    [SerializeField] private float currTime;
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more information about what you're trying to accomplish and what you've done already, otherwise others will not understand what your problem is. Please be more specific and elaborate on your problem for others to be able to help you.

Comment: Can you re-explain what you’re trying to achieve? Functions don’t have serialised fields.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but that still isn't clear enough. Do you want to call a method from another class? What kind of method are we talking about? Where is the method currently defined? Show us some code, so that we can understand the issue

Comment: [Asking a good question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the Unity Inspector to store and serialise classes, you would expose the class as a field. The Inspector will then let you drag and drop a class into the object field.

```cs
public class Countdown : MonoBehaviour
{
    // A reference to the GameActions class is serialised here.
    [SerializeField] private GameActions _gameActions;
    [SerializeField] private float currTime;

    // This is an example of a countdown timer.
    private void Update ( )
    {
        currTime -= Time.deltaTime;
        if ( currTime < 0 )
        {
            // This is how you call the GameActions actionStart method.
            _gameActions.actionStart ( );
            this.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, I just meant that I don't want Conutdown class to know anything about GameActions class, it should just recieve some function and call it when needed. I assume there is no way do this in C#.

Comment: @LobanovIvan in C# you can have a reference to a method via various mechanisms, for example `Func`, but Unity will not serialise those references for you, without using third party tools. You would need to set the reference to the method yourself.